# How to include child terms within parent?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, children

I have the following for a specific term ID:

```
<?php if (!is_tax( 'listing_category', '542' )) { ?>
test1
    <?php else: ?>
 test2
<?php } else {  ?>
```

This works great for making test2 appear within term 542, but I want to include all of its child terms as well. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Where are you using it? inside or outside loop?

Comment: You could start with [`get_term_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children)

Comment: I don't know what a loop is but I have it in the header.php file.